# Move bones in armature

Tags: rigging

I need to export my Blender to Unity, to use with IKinema plugin. The plugin needs a certain bone structure, starting with 'root'. Blender has made another bone above 'root', called 'armature' (marked with red line), which is exported with the FBX and recognized as a bone in Unity. 
 [image]

How can I move 'root' to be the actual root bone?

Thanks so much!

Comment: An armature is definitely not a bone. The first bone is the one called the Root.

Comment: @Tak thank you! But why is Armature twice in the list? And how can I remove the second one?

Comment: The difference is that one of them represents the object and the other represents the armature.